# Losing data when forwarding ellipsis args

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-c++

I am looking to have a portable debug class since i plan to work on the project on various platforms. This class provides methods to write messages through XDebug.WriteLine("I like number %d", 7); Which internally redirects the arguments to the system specific method.

This requires me to pass the ellipsis data as a parameter. And here is the problem. It works on integers, but loses floats on pass through.

```
XDebug::WriteLine("Print numbers %f, %f",1.234, 3.210f);
XDebug::odprintf(L"Print numbers %f, %f",1.234, 3.210f);
```

outputs

```
Print numbers 0.000000, 0.000000
Print numbers 1.234000, 3.210000
```

I am trying to figure out where the arguments get mangled. Would appreciate your help. The entire debug class is below.

```
#pragma once
#ifndef _XDEBUG_H_
#define _XDEBUG_H_

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <Windows.h>;

class XDebug
{
public:

    static void __cdecl WriteLine(const char* txt, ...){
        #if (CC_TARGET_PLATFORM == CC_PLATFORM_WIN32)

        int stringSize = MultiByteToWideChar (CP_ACP, 0, txt, -1, NULL, 0);
        wchar_t* buffer = new wchar_t[stringSize];
        MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8 , 0 , txt, -1, buffer, stringSize);

        va_list args;
        va_start(args, txt);
        XDebug::odprintf(buffer,args);

        delete buffer;

        #endif
    }

//private:
#if (CC_TARGET_PLATFORM == CC_PLATFORM_WIN32)
    static void __cdecl odprintf(const wchar_t *format, ...){
    wchar_t    buf[4096], *p = buf;
    va_list args;
    int     n;

            va_start(args, format);
            n = _vsnwprintf(p, sizeof buf - 3, format, args); // buf-3 is room for CR/LF/NUL
            va_end(args);

            p += (n < 0) ? sizeof buf - 3 : n;

            while ( p > buf  &&  isspace(p[-1]) )
                    *--p = '\0';

            *p++ = '\r';
            *p++ = '\n';
            *p   = '\0';

            OutputDebugString(buf);
    }
#endif
};

#endif
```

Comment: Do you really need that ? *really* ? `Boost.Format` manages to do without. If your compiler does not support variadic template yet, then have a look at boost managed using operator overloading, it makes for a cleaner syntax.

Comment: I wasn't aware of it. Thanks. Your answer sent me on a longer trip than i expected. Boost seems like a massive set of libraries, i'll try it out, but for the immediate purposes I am really hoping things can be done with bare bone simplicity.

Thank you though, i'll study Boost in more depth. Also apparently VS2010 is not C11, so no variadic templates yet.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2011/09/12/10209291.aspx

Comment: Boost is a repository of libraries, so there are a lot of them but fortunately they are not too interdependent. There are humpfteenths of libraries I have never even glanced at, my recommendation is to check Boost when you have a particular issue to see if anything matches your requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot forward varargs between functions like that, for the same reason that you can't pass `args` directly to `sprintf` (you have to use a special `vsprintf`).

I suggest writing an overload of `odprintf` that takes a `va_list` object as a parameter.  (And to avoid [duplication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DRY), you could then implement the original `odprintf` in terms of the new overload.)